# How do use pivot a table and cumulate them?

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset which has two destinations and the distance between them.

| city1 | city2 | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 102 | 56 |
| 102 | 103 | 34 |
| 103 | 104 | 6 |
| 104 | 105 | 15 |

I want to prepare a table which will have the cumulative distance with city1 as the index and city2 as the columns! and the values of the distance must be cumulative sum.
The diagonal elements must be 0 as well!

Tried this using the cumsum() to first find the cumulative sum, and added it as a new column -

`df3['cs'] = np.cumsum(df3['distance'])`

I tried doing this using the pivot method.

```
pivot_table = df3.pivot(index='city1', columns='city2', values='cs')
```

But the resulting table had the following output:

[image: output (CLICK HERE)]

I want result having diagonal columns 0 and the others being the cumulative sum....

Anyone with a solution to it?

Expected Output -

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Please provide expected output for your example data. It is not clear what you mean by cummulative sum.

Comment: Hey, I have attached the expected output! Please do check and please help me finish it!

Answer (score 0):

There's a small issue with the data sample you sent. It looks like you're missing the route from city 104 to city 105.

Anyway, here's a Python code that might help. It calculates distances between the cities in your dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
data = {
    'city1': [101, 102, 103, 104],
    'city2': [102, 103, 104, 105],
    'distance': [56, 34, 6, 15]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cities = df[['city1', 'city2']].values.flatten()

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(index=np.unique(cities), columns=list(cities))

# compute distance
combination_cities = np.array(np.meshgrid(cities, cities)).T.reshape(-1, 2)

def compute_distance(c1, c2):
    if c1>c2:
        c1,c2 = c2,c1
    if c1 == c2:
        return 0
    else:
        distances = {}
        destination_city=None
        from_city = c1
        while destination_city != c2:
            df_tmp = df[df['city1'] == from_city]
            if df_tmp.empty:
                return np.nan
            destination_city = df_tmp['city2'].values[0]
            distance = df_tmp['distance'].values[0]
            distances[destination_city] = distance
            from_city = destination_city
        return sum(distances.values())


for c1,c2 in combination_cities:
    distance = compute_distance(c1, c2)
    df_2.loc[c1, c2] = distance
    df_2.loc[c2, c1] = distance

# df_2 = df_2.fillna(0)
print(df_2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the solution. But, I have replaced the input table with a new one and attached an expected output table! Can you please can go through it and help me in this?

Comment: @KishoreKumar, I update the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`networkx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length.html#all-pairs-dijkstra-path-length) to calculate all shortest distances:

```py
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source="city1", target="city2", edge_attr="distance")

out = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"city1": c1, "city2": c2, "distance": d}
        for c1, rest in nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G, weight="distance")
        for c2, d in rest.items()
    ]
)
print(out.pivot(index="city1", columns="city2", values="distance"))
```

Prints:

```
city2  101  102  103  104  105
city1                         
101      0   56   90   96  111
102     56    0   34   40   55
103     90   34    0    6   21
104     96   40    6    0   15
105    111   55   21   15    0
```